# How can I get unique values in array in a jmespath query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

In an aws cli jmespath query, with for example the output `["a","a","b","a","b"]`, how do i extract the unique values of it to get `["a","b"]`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible in jmespath.

Comment: I would argue that jmespath is grep, not gawk.  It just provides a selection of data.  That is it's job.  Processing json is someone else's business! :-)  Now what that other tool should be is another question and I think the answer depends on context.

Answer (score 7):

It's not what you asked for but I've used the following:

```
aws ... | jq -r ".[]" | sort | uniq
```

This will convert `["a", "a", "b", "a"]` to:

```
a
b
```

Comment: This is a great workaround. In PowerShell on Windows, I installed `jq` with `winget install stedolan.jq`. You may need the latest winget 1.4 `winget install winget`.  Then `| jq -r ".[]" | sort` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've come to "unique values"... is to deduplicate outside of JMESPath (so not really in JMESPath pipelines).

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
   --region us-east-1 \
   --filter "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64" \
   --query 'Images[].ImageOwnerAlias | join(`"\n"`, @)' \
   --output text \
| sort -u
```

Output:
amazon
aws-marketplace

If you use JMESPath standalone, you'd write things like this.

```
jp -u -f myjson.json 'Images[].ImageOwnerAlias | join(`"\n"`, @)' | sort -u
```

The idea is to get jp to spit out a list of values (on separate lines) and then apply all the power of your favorite sorter.  The tricky part is to get the list (of course).